# Angular / Firestore - How to set a URL param inside a service

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, url-parameters

I'm creating a service which looks at a firestore collection. As a test I hardcoded the location of this collection for my AngularFire query:

```
/users/myuserIDGoesHere/shop/shopIDGoesHere/issues
```

However, 'shopID' returns undefined if i try to grab it from the URL parameters in my service:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => { 
  this.shopId = params['shopId'];
});
```

If I use the same code in my component, the shopId is read correctly from the URL. However, by that time my service has already tried to run with an undefined id.

Is there a way I get get url params to be used in my service?

**My Service**

This query never succeeds because "shopId" is never defined.

```
this.issueCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`/users/${myUserId}/shops/${shopId}/issues`, ref => {
   return ref.orderBy('issue_order');
});
```

**From my component**

Inside my component constructor I tried to apply url param and apply it to my service. However, my service runs before the component can send it over to the service.

```
this.activatedRoute.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
  issuesService.shopId = urlParameters['shopId'];
});
```

**UPDATE**

In my component I am now grabbing the URL in the constructor and then calling the service.

```
this.activatedRoute.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
  this.issuesService.shopId = urlParameters['shopId'];
  this.issuesService.getIssueData();
});
```

Is this the correct way to do it? I mean, it works. But if I want other components to also use this service, does that mean I also need to call 'getIssueData()' from the components I want to use it? Even if 'getIssueData()' is grabbing all the items in the collection, along with their associated image URLs etc.

Comment: Could you add more info? Like what have you tried? Or how do you pass the url params to your service?

Comment: Hi, sure. I thought there was enough there. But I've added some more code that might help :)